# Hover over opaque menu

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-animate, viewport

Here is my fancy menu.

```
        <script type="text/javascript">

        $('#brand_logo').bind('inview', function(event, visible) {
            if (visible == true) {
                // console.log("visible");
                $("#topnav").animate({
                    opacity: 1.0
                });
                // $(".head-wrap-left").hide();
            } else {
                // console.log("invisible");

                $("#topnav").animate({
                    opacity: 0.6
                });
                // $(".head-wrap-left").show();
            }
        }); 

        </script>​
```

There is only one problem.. If the user reloads the page and the element is NOT in viewport, it defaults to 1.0 opacity. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to bind inview and mouseenter?
Like this:

```
 $('#brand_logo').bind('inview mouseenter', function(event, visible) {..}
```

You don't need to use .find Your inview event should be triggered if it is in viewport on refresh or load.

Comment: thank you for your input. That did not work. If it is reloaded and #brand_logo is NOT in viewport, the #topnav is defaulted to full opacity (1.0). I want it be at the 0.6 if the #brand_logo is not in viewport no matter what. The hover effect you suggested didn't work either.